# Filling option failing when ListLinePlot given my data

Tags: plotting

### Context

I want to do Filled plot such as:

```
dat1 = {Table[{i^2, i + 1}, {i, 5}], Table[{i^2, i}, {i, 5}]}
ListLinePlot[dat1, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I apply this to my own data:

```
dat = 
{
  {{3.0779456558039593`, 3.842486584798708`}, 
   {1.2951669675555262`, 4.05402324780319`}, 
   {0.9196161755899819`, 3.939944632202657`}, 
   {0.5722748507275665`, 3.8875332289711`}, 
   {0.29373287932080444`, 3.7317102841786385`}},
  {{3.0779456558039593`, 7.125115694053534`}, 
   {1.2951669675555262`, 5.8724983311100605`}, 
   {0.9196161755899819`, 5.707473500231869`}, 
   {0.5722748507275665`, 5.114513590881306`}, 
   {0.29373287932080444`, 4.240800591615147`}}
}
```

It fails to fill the region:

```
ListLinePlot[dat, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Question

> Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: See update to my answer for _brief_ discussion of why this is not a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause is your data is out of order. So, the workaround is

```
ListLinePlot[SortBy[First] /@ dat, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

I believe it is not a bug. Or, at least, it is an issue that is tangentially discussed in the `ListLinePlot` [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/09b5cde4y-huzonq). So, while this is certainly disconcerting to see, unusual behavior with unsorted data is expected.

Comment: its actually just reversed.. so `Reverse /@ dat` works too.

Comment: @rcollyer thanks! Should I leave the question for reference?

Comment: @chris yes, please.