# Filling option failing when used with ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

As mentioned in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95973/filling-option-failing-when-listlineplot-given-my-data) the following filling seems to work well.

```
dat1 = {Table[{i^2, i + 1}, {i, 5}], Table[{i^2, i}, {i, 5}]}
ListLinePlot[dat1, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Question

Why does this not work as expected? (i.e. put a shaded area?)

```
ListLogLinearPlot[dat1, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Attempt

I guess I would could do something like this

```
dat2 = dat1 /. {x_?NumberQ, y_} :> {Log10[x],y};
ListLinePlot[dat2, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but the axes are not logarithmic;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Joined` option will achieve your desired effect.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[dat1, Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 FillingStyle -> LightPink, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: arg… that's pretty obvious retrospectively :-) Thanks. Should I remove the questions? I think WRI should had a new function (they seem to like doing that `ListLineLogLinearPlot ` !)

Comment: @chris happens to us all...I suspect it will be cleaned up as  "simple mistake" (which I have made many, and which sounds more pejorative than intended) or you can delete if you want. I think sometimes these "doh" moments can be helpful to others. :)