# Filling between points in ListPlot only works with points in certain order

Tags: plotting, bugs, filling

I am working on more flexible version of [`ErrorListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) from the [`ErrorBarPlots`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/guide/ErrorBarPlottingPackage.html)package.

The basic idea is that I `ListPlot` three lists of points; the data itself and then two more lists which contain the upper and lower bounds of the error bar. I then use [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) to create the error bar between them.

Here is an example:

```
someData = {{{-(222/125), 6143/1000}, {67/25, 5287/1000}, {617/200, 3759/500}}, {{-(222/125), 2803/500}, {67/25, 598/125}, {617/200, 3397/500}}, {{-(222/125), 2937/500}, {67/25, 1259/250}, {617/200, 1789/250}}};
ListPlot[
 someData, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}},
 Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

The result is

[image]

but if I plot the three lists with the points in a different order (in this case just reversed) then the filling doesn't work:

```
ListPlot[
 Reverse/@someData, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}},
 Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: List plot where filling doesn't work]

**Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is this a bug?**

The best I have come up with at the moment is to just keep plotting my data in different orders until it works...

Comment: I see the same strange behavior using Mathematica 8.0.4 on Windows x64.

Comment: It seems that `Filling` works on ordered datapoints...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas yes that seems to be true on the various trials I have attempted. Interesting

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug to *Wolfram Support*?

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Filling option failing when ListLinePlot given my data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95973/125)

Comment: I have not reported as a bug. I wasn’t confident enough I hadn’t missed something stupid

Comment: I can confirm, with Mathematica 12.0, the list of data (the x-axis) needs to be sorted for filling to work. In my case, I solved this issue like this:
plotData = SortBy[{x,y}\[Transpose],First] where "x" is a vector of unsorted x values with their corresponding y values.